# Forwarding requests UDPSocket

Tags: ruby, network-programming, dns, udp, eventmachine

I have a basic ruby program, that listens on a port (53), receives the data and then sends to another location (Google DNS server - 8.8.8.8). The responses are not going back to their original destination, or I'm not forwarding them correctly.

Here is the code. NB I'm using EventMachine

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

module DNSServer
    def post_init
        puts 'connected'
    end

    def receive_data(data)
        # Forward all data
        conn = UDPSocket.new
        conn.connect '8.8.8.8', 53
        conn.send data, 0
        conn.close

        p data.unpack("H*")
    end

    def unbind
        puts 'disconnected'
    end
end
EM.run do
    EM.open_datagram_socket '0.0.0.0', 53, DNSServer
end
```

Any thoughts as to why or tips to debug, would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious problems are:

1. UDP comms are usually connectionless, use the 4 argument version of `send` instead of `connect`
2. You're not receiving any data from the socket talking to 8.8.8.8
3. You're not sending any data back (`#send_data`) to the original client

This seems to work:

```
require 'socket'
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

module DNSServer
    def receive_data(data)
        # Forward all data
        conn = UDPSocket.new
        conn.send data, 0, '8.8.8.8', 53
        send_data conn.recv 4096
    end
end

EM.run do
    EM.open_datagram_socket '0.0.0.0', 53, DNSServer
end
```